# como buscar numero de una cifra en una cadena con varios números

Tags: linux, bash, script

Tengo esta cadena:

```
FILE="serie temporada 1 cap 2.mp4"
```

y quiero que a los numeros se les agregue un cero `0`, de tal manera que quede así:

```
"serie temporada 01 cap 02.mp4"
```

Intenté esto:

```
N1=$(grep -o [0-9] <<< "$FILE")
echo "${FILE//"$N1"/0"$N1"}"
```

**¡Pero sólo funciona para cadenas que tengan un solo número!**

¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si dispones de `sed` y un poco de expresiones regulares podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
echo "serie temporada 1 cap 2.mp4" | sed -r 's/\b([0-9])\b/0\1/g'

> serie temporada 01 cap 02.mp4
```

En tu caso algo como esto

```
FILE="serie temporada 1 cap 2.mp4"; echo $FILE | sed -r 's/\b([0-9])\b/0\1/g'
```

Con esto `\b([0-9])\b` buscamos un patrón donde tengamos un **`separador de palabra + dígito + separador de palabra`**, lo cual resuelve la necesidad de capturar solo aquellos casos de un solo dígito.

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciona como debería, ahora me gustaría saber si podría editar solo aquellos números con una cifra, de manera que quede así:

"serie temporada 11 cap 02.mp4"

donde el el numero de dos cifras "11" no se le agregue el cero 'o'

Comment: @juenDiegoGuzman, ahí edité la respuesta,pensaba que lo de un solo dígito tenía que ver con que solo procesabas la primer ocurrencia.

Comment: EXELENTE!!! es lo que estaba buscando, Muchísimas gracias maestro, no sabe  lo importante que era para mi el resolver esto. GRACIAS!!!

Comment: Hola nuevamente, veo que el comando solo funciona cuando el numero tiene un espacio. En una cadena como esta "serie_temporada_1_cap_2.mp4" no funciona

Comment: @juenDiegoGuzman, claro, el `\b` es un `word boundarie` que no incluye el guión. Si además de espacios va a tener guiones, te sugiero esta expresión regular: `sed -r 's/[ |_]([0-9])[ |_|.]/ 0\1 /g'`

Comment: Creo que ya entendí la variación.. muchas gracias profe

Comment: ¡Buena respuesta! Nótese que si quieres repetir lo que has cogido íntegramente, con `&` hay suficiente: `sed -r 's/\b[0-9]\b/0&/g'`.